# Putting geolocation coordinates into array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, geolocation, coordinates

I'm trying to put my geolocation coordinates gathered during watchPosition() into an array, so that I can work out total distance later.

I have create a new array

```
 var mapArray;
 mapArray = new Array();
```

then where I assigning my latitude and longitude im putting the values to the array

```
   document.getElementById("currentLat").innerHTML = (position.coords.latitude);
    document.getElementById("currentLong").innerHTML = (position.coords.longitude);
    document.getElementById("mySpeed").innerHTML = (speedValue.toFixed(1));

 mapArray.push(currentLat);
 mapArray.push(currentLong);//put values in array
```

I then want to output them to check it has worked so have tried converting the array to a string

```
 function getArray(){

 var outputData = mapArray.toString();
 document.getElementById("arrayresult").innerHTML = (outputData);

  }
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong at all?
At the moment the output is just 'HTML.SpanElement],[object' over and over again.

thanks.

Comment: What is `currentLat` and `currentLong`?

Comment: @KJPrice the current latitude and longitude that changes using watchPosition. I want to store the value in the array either every time the value changes or every few seconds

Comment: Yeah you should really include all of that in your code above. From what your code says, `currentLat` is `undefined` which we know is not true.

Comment: try using innerText instead of innerHTML, unless id="currentLat" or id="currentLong" is an input in which case use .value

Comment: i was assuming that the way i had gone about adding it to the array was incorrect, thats why i've concentrated on showing that part of the code for if anyone could see any immediate issues with how i'd written it.

Comment: @Plentybinary will give innerText a go thanks.

Comment: @KJPrice - I had actually misspelt the variables further up! haha. Brought it to my attention so thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an array, don't use `new Array()`, use the array literal `[]` instead, and then we can just assign the whole thing in one go:

```
var mapArray = [
  position.coords.latitude,
  position.coords.longitude
];
```

But, since you already have that convenient `position` object, why not just rely on that:

```
function showPosition(position) {
  // grab all the keys in position.coords
  var keys = Object.keys(position.coords);

  // and then map them to "key: value" strings
  var pairs = keys.map(function(key) {
    return key + ": " + position.coords[key];
  });

  // join them up with commas between them, and ONLY between them:
  var stringified = pairs.join(", ");

  // and then set that as our on-page container text
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = stringified;
}
```

And of course we can tighten that since it's fairly straight forward code:

```
function showPosition(position) {
  var result = Object.keys(position.coords).map(function(key) {
                 return key + ": " + position.coords[key];
               }).join(", ");
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = result
}
```

We're also using `textContent` here, just in case `position.coords` contains funny keys or values. Setting it as text content, rather than HTML content, means there's no content that can accidentally trigger.